# Access Ember application from outer scope

Tags: ember.js

I need to get access to the controller model from the script that will run 
outside of the ember scope. Also, is it possible to send actions in the same way?

Please give few examples.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

The purpose: I am getting new model from my chrome extension and i need to set it to the current 
controller and update view.

Comment: It's possible but not recommended. Can you tell us more about your use case?

Comment: @GJK, please check updates in the topic.

Comment: A better title might be "Access Ember application from Chrome extension".

Comment: I think "Access Ember application from outer scope" is better, because this is useful not only for chrome extension.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think this an interesting question and I did a little digging to figure out an answer.

### Getting the application

You may know that your Ember app is using a global variable like `window.MyEmberApp`. In that case, getting your application is easy. If you don't know where the app is then it is a little trickier.

I pulled this code from from [the Ember Inspector](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-inspector):

```
function getApplication() {
  var namespaces = Ember.Namespace.NAMESPACES,
      application;

  namespaces.forEach(function(namespace) {
    if(namespace instanceof Ember.Application) {
      application = namespace;
      return false;
    }
  });
  return application;
}
```

### Getting your instantiated controller

You can use the container to get access to your instantiated controller from your application:

```
var controller = app.__container__.lookup('controller:elephant');
controller.set('model', newModel);
```

Where 'elephant' is the name of your controller.

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by 'send actions', but yes, you could reach into the actions object of your controller and call those functions.

```
controller.actions.myAction.call(controller, 'arg1', 'arg2');
```

Good luck with your Chrome extension!

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Seems to be that is what i need.